# Replacing values in pandas dataframe column with same row value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
            val_1   val_2   Flag
Date                       
2018-08-27  221.0  121.0     0
2018-08-28  222.0  122.0     1
2018-08-29  223.0  123.0     0
2018-08-30  224.0  124.0     2
2018-08-31  225.0  125.0     0
```

I want to change the Flag column values to the same values from other columns based on Flag condition. Namely, if Flag is 1 replace 1 with val_1 from the same row and if Flag is 2 replace it with val_2. The output that I am looking would look like this:

```
            val_1   val_2   Flag
Date                       
2018-08-27  221.0  121.0     0
2018-08-28  222.0  122.0     222.0
2018-08-29  223.0  123.0     0
2018-08-30  224.0  124.0     124.0
2018-08-31  225.0  125.0     0
```

I know that I can use `.loc` like this `df.loc[df['Flag'] == 1, ['Flag']] =`. I don't know what goes to the right hand side of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One other way is to use np.where for `numpy.where(condtion,yes,no)`

In this case, I use nested `np.where` so that

*`np.where(If Flag=2,take val_2,(take x)) where takex is another np.where`*

```
df['Flag']=np.where(df['Flag']==1,df['val_1'],(np.where(df['Flag']==2,df['val_2'],df['Flag'])))
df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: `np.select` is better than two nested `np.where`

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang, of course learning from the best absolutely humbled. I now know!

Answer (score 4):

Few ways you could do this, firstly your initial code is very close, you just need to end the assignment :

```
df.loc[df['Flag'] == 1, 'Flag'] = df['val_1']
print(df)
         Date  val_1  val_2   Flag
0  2018-08-27  221.0  121.0    0.0
1  2018-08-28  222.0  122.0  222.0
2  2018-08-29  223.0  123.0    0.0
3  2018-08-30  224.0  124.0    2.0
4  2018-08-31  225.0  125.0    0.0
```

what you're doing here is filtering your dataframe and replacing the values where the conditions matches. in this iinstance where Flag is equal to one.

since you're making muliple assingments, lets use `np.select`

```
import numpy as np
conditions = [df['Flag'].eq(1),
             df['Flag'].eq(2)]


choices = [df['val_1'],df['val_2']]

df['Flag'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=df['Flag'])
```

What this this does is evaulate any and all conditions you have. leaving the default as the original column. You can add more conditions in, and wrap OR statements in parenthsis with a | (pipe) sepreators. i.e `[(df['Flag'] == 1 | df['Flag'] == 2)]`

```
         Date  val_1  val_2   Flag
0  2018-08-27  221.0  121.0    0.0
1  2018-08-28  222.0  122.0  222.0
2  2018-08-29  223.0  123.0    0.0
3  2018-08-30  224.0  124.0  124.0
4  2018-08-31  225.0  125.0    0.0
```

Comment: For now I am using the simple one-liner solution @wwnde, but I very much like your choices for more complex conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
new_vals = df.lookup(df.index, df.columns[df.Flag-1])

df['Flag'] = df.Flag.mask(df.Flag>0, new_val)
```

**Note**: as commented by @Erfan, this would also work:

```
df['Flag'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.columns[df.Flag-1])
```

Output:

```
            val_1  val_2  Flag
Date                          
2018-08-27  221.0  121.0     0
2018-08-28  222.0  122.0   222
2018-08-29  223.0  123.0     0
2018-08-30  224.0  124.0   124
2018-08-31  225.0  125.0     0
```

Comment: The `mask` is not needed right? The lookup is sufficient.

Comment: @Erfan apparently, you are correct. That's just because `Flag` is the `-1`-th column :-).